# Why my freebsd has several sendmail processes?

Tags: unix, freebsd, sendmail

While using freebsd 8.2, I noticed, by `top`, that several `sendmail` processes are always running. I never explicitly start any of them. Is it safe if I just kill them? And how can I detect which program(s) created them?

Comment: What is reported by `ps` about the processes?  Sendmail usually reports process state in info reported by `ps`.

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip `ps aux` shows they are from `/usr/sbin/sendmail -FCronDaemon -odi -oem -oi -t` any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal, some sendmail processes are started by default so that the system can send mail for example from cron. If you don't want them, be aware that things like that will break. You can disable them by adding

```
  sendmail_enable="NONE"
```

to your `/etc/rc.conf`.